# What's a good way to enable access to private members of another instance of a class template in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a polygon class:

```
// A polygon is multiple (possibly closed) polycurves.
template <typename T, typename P = _point<T,2>>
struct _polygon {
    using point  = P;

    // default constructor
    _polygon() {
        offs_.push_back(0);
    }

    // build polygon from another type
    template <typename U>
    _polygon(const _polygon<U> &poly) {
        pnts_.reserve(poly.pnts_.size());
        offs_ = poly.offs_;
        for (const auto& pnt : poly.pnts_) {
            pnts_.push_back(point(pnt));
        }
    }

private:
    vector<point> pnts_; // list of points
    vector<int>   offs_; // offsets of start of polychains
};
```

The issue is in the converting constructor.  I get an errror when accessing members of the other _polygon type:

> polygon.h:376:28: error: ‘std::vector,
>   std::allocator > >
>   sk::_new_polygon::pnts_’ is private within this context
>            pnts_.reserve(poly.pnts_.size());

Clearly an instance of a class template C isn't friends/doesn't have visibility into another instance C, which is a little surprising to me.  How can I get access to the other polygon's internals to do the conversion in this case?

Comment: `polygon<X>` is a different type than `polygon<Y>` (if `X<>Y`), and `polygon` is not a class per-se. Declare some appropriate friend relationship, or use some appropriate base class?

Answer (score 3):

Just declare your other template as a friend:

```
template <typename T, typename P>
friend class _polygon;
```

I live the wisdom of naming your class with a name beginning with underscore to the other question.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I knew about the template friend feature, but having a second templated parameter was throwing me.